# Image Gallery using meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm using meteor to make a web page. A large part of the web page is Galleries of images. Is there an easy way to keep information about the images and either the images themselves or links to the images in a mongoDB such that a gallery can be created on the fly to suit details entered by the site user?

Comment: So in a nutshell "which plugin/module or meteorite" will actually do all this for me? See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about StackOverflow's policies on this question, but I'll tell you what you can do.

First you'll need a way to upload images. There's a package called lepozepo which will perform that for you.

After you have that, you'll take the urls that lepozeop generates for you and save this to a collection. There are a number of ways you can do this, if you know javascript you know at least two ways to accomplish this.

Once your collection is saving the urls for you, you just have a template that returns to you the image entries from the collection by using a meteor helper. It would look something like:

```
Template.gallery.helpers({
   images: function(){
        return imageCollection.find();
   }
});
```

And in your template

```
{{#each images}}
    <img src="{{url}}>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thankyou for responding my question was a bit vague, first time I've posted on Stackoverflow. I'll repost the question when I've figured a bit more out myself. But basically I have 1000 joinery product photos; windows doors conservatories staircases and such and I would like to put them all up on the website in one directory but then tag the images for what they contain eg; oak, window, conservatory, double-glazed, painted, general rating /100, date, etc, etc. then allow the user to refinetheir search to show the most relevant photos.